# Split an std::set into vectors of equal size

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have an std::set of integers of say 550 elements. I want to split this into vectors of size 100 or less. So, lets say, in this case we will get 6 vectors in all. First 5 vectors will be of sizes 100 and the sixth vector will be of size 50.

So, effectively I need to break std::setmasterSet into std::vector>final. Is there a good and crisp way to do it using some standard std algorithms. I dont need a class to have this logic, infact I can write a function to do this.

Comment: just go ahead and do it, I wont stop you

Answer (score 3):

Hmm...I guess you could do something on this general order:

```
std::vector<vector<int>> ints(myset.size()/max_size);

size_t i = 0;

for (auto d : my_set) 
    ints[i++/max_size].push_back(d);
```